# How to store data except a particular row in a table and apply commands to that result

Tags: sql-server, mysqli

I want to exclude a particular row in the table having the mobile in it and select rows in the result which have the newmobile in it.

```
select * from user where mobile = (select * from user where mobile !='$newmobile')
```

The output is:
     Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
select * from user 
where mobile IN (
    select mobile from user where mobile !='$newmobile'
)
```

Note:
1) subselect should return one column, as you're trying to match a column to the returned value.
2) using IN allows your subselect to return more than 1 value